# SQL Error [933] [42000]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, dbeaver

I have a problem with some SQL queries in Oracle and I don't understand why, maybe you could help me.

When I try to call two simple queries, one after another, I constantly receive this error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

When I said two simple queries, I mean, for example (of course, the tables were already created, I am not trying to drop not exist tables):

```
DROP TABLE Table1;
DROP TABLE Table2;
```

But if I run the queries individually, it works, does anyone know why? I can't see why they are not properly ended.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm using DBeaver.

Comment: I don't know DBeaver, but - some tools expect one empty line between commands.

Comment: I tried to leave an empty line but it doesn't work, but thanks!

Comment: I don't even know what DBeaver is, but a quick Google search revealed this: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2244 Apparently you can submit "statements" or "scripts", and - I assume - whatever it is that you are doing is viewed as a "statement" submission. That thread shows how to submit multiple statements at once.

Comment: Did you try to run these statements by pressing `Alt + X`?

Comment: you can't run two statements as one.

Comment: Thank you all! It was that, so easy, sorry for my noob question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Littlefoot got it right.Click third button on left pane or keyboard short cut is `ALT+X`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the command in an application other than SQL Dev, you will easily get the error: ***"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"***, my advice is to remove the ";" for the code to work properly,
Below is an example

```
private void ExcuteOracleCommand(string[] sqlFiles, OracleTransaction transaction, List<string> commands)
    {
        try
        {
            using (transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                if (dbManager.GetState() == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    foreach (string file in sqlFiles)
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                        string sqlScript = File.ReadAllText(file);

                        try
                        {
                            using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                            {
                                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                command.Transaction = transaction;
                                commands = SplitString(sqlScript);
                                
                                if (commands.Count < 1)
                                {
                                    Utils.ReturnStatus("File: " + fileName + " execute failed", " No valid data", tb_stt);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    foreach (string commandText in commands)
                                    {
                                        command.CommandText = commandText.Trim().Replace(";", "");

                                        try
                                        {
                                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        }
                                        catch (OracleException ex)
                                        {
                                            Utils.ReturnStatus("File: " + fileName + " execute fail", ex.Message, tb_stt);
                                            transaction.Rollback();
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    Utils.ReturnStatus("Transaction committed. File: " + fileName + " executed successfully", "", tb_stt);
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                        catch (OracleException ex)
                        {
                            string errorMessage = $"Oracle error occurred: {ex.Message}\nStackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}";
                            Utils.ReturnStatus("File: " + fileName + " execute failed", errorMessage, tb_stt);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Utils.ReturnStatus("File: " + fileName + " execute failed", ex.Message, tb_stt);
                        }
                    }

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.ReturnStatus("Error occurred", ex.Message, tb_stt);
        }
        finally
        {
            transaction?.Dispose();
            dbManager.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

here, I have removed ";" for it to work, otherwise it will make the same error as you, even though it is syntactically correct