# getting error while executing drop package command in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, package, dbeaver

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE employee2 AS
  PROCEDURE proce(f_name varchar2, l_name varchar2);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY employee2 AS
  PROCEDURE proce(f_name varchar2, l_name varchar2) IS
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO emp2(f_name, l_name) VALUES(f_name, l_name);
  END;
END employee2;

BEGIN
  employee2.proce('bat', 'man');
END;
```

this code runs correctly and bat man get inserted to the table which i created.

but when it comes to dropping the package

```
DROP PACKAGE employee2;
```

it throws the following error;

> SQL Error [933] [42000]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

help me out with this

Comment: That cannot be PostgreSQL, since it has no packages.

Comment: Did you look at [this possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64405334/sql-error-933-42000-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended)?

Comment: Depends how you're running it, but at a guess you might need to remove the semicolon from the end?